# Find all roots of the polynomial $f(x)=x^3-[1]_p$ in $\mathbb{Z}/1729\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

Problem is the same as in the title, Find roots of the polynomial $f(x)=x^3-[1]_p$ in $\mathbb{Z}/1729\mathbb{Z}$. I am specifically asking only for someone to point me in the direction of the method required to solve this equation and find all of its values, and whether there is an algorithm to determine all 27 of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1729=7\cdot 13\cdot 19$, so solve $x^3=1$ modulo $7$, $13$, and $19$, and combine the solutions using the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

([Obviously](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1729_(number)) both $-12$ and $1$ are solutions, so modulo $7$ and $19$ this gives you two different roots and you can find the third by polynomial division. This won't work modulo 13, but there are not that many possibilities to check by brute force).

Comment: I got 1, 2, 4 for 7; 1, 3, 9 for 13; and 1, 7, 11 for 19. I had already found these, and used the chinese remainder theorem to determine that 1729 will have 27 solutions. My problem was how exactly do solutions get combined. Multiplying combinations of these does not exactly work.

Comment: @Hereami: Well, when you ask to be "pointed in the direction" of something, it behooves you to explain _up front_ **where you are**. Otherwise you will get answers that are based on the default assumption that you haven't gotten anywhere yet, so you'll be told the direction to take _from the starting point_.